# Is this code fragment a genetic algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to learn genetic algorthms and AI developement and I copied this code from a book, but I don't know if it is a proper genetic algorithm.
Here is the code (`main.py`):

```
import random

geneSet = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!.,1234567890-_=+!@#$%^&*():'[]\""
target = input()

def generate_parent(length):
    genes = []
    while len(genes) < length:
        sampleSize = min(length - len(genes), len(geneSet))
        genes.extend(random.sample(geneSet, sampleSize))
    parent = ""
    for i in genes:
        parent += i
    return parent

def get_fitness(guess):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(target)):
        if target[i] == guess[i]:
            total = total + 1
    return total
    """
    return sum(1 for expected, actual in zip(target, guess)
        if expected == actual)
    """

def mutate(parent):
    index = random.randrange(0, len(parent))
    childGenes = list(parent)
    newGene, alternate = random.sample(geneSet, 2)
    if newGene == childGenes[index]:
       childGenes[index] = alternate
    else:
       childGenes[index] = newGene
    child = ""
    for i in childGenes:
        child += i

    return child

random.seed()
bestParent = generate_parent(len(target))
bestFitness = get_fitness(bestParent)
print(bestParent)

while True:
    child = mutate(bestParent)
    childFitness = get_fitness(child)
    if bestFitness >= childFitness:
        continue
    print(str(child) + "\t" + str(get_fitness(child)))
    if childFitness >= len(bestParent):
        break
    bestFitness = childFitness
    bestParent = child
```

I saw that it has the fitness function and the mutate function, but it doesn't generate a population and I don't understand why. I thaught that a genetic algorithm needs a population generation and a crossover from the best population members to the new generation. Is this a proper genetic algorithm?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Sure it generates a population. I see `child = mutate(bestParent)` what do you have after you do that a few thousand times?

Comment: It is an evolutionary algorithm, not a genetic algorithm...

Comment: @Octopus Well, I have a member of every generation, but only one member per generation

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what is an evolutionary algorithm?

Comment: Only one? Why's that? How many times does the code after `while True` run?

Comment: @Octopus: the population is always limited to a parent and a child. So there are no two parents that produce a new child.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Exactly

Comment: Some genetic algorithm will include crossover rules, but that is not a necessity of a genetic algorithm. [There are *selection rules*, *crossover rules* and *mutation rules*.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/what-is-the-genetic-algorithm.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com) This seems to have 2 of the three so strictly speaking it is a genetic algorithm.

Comment: So far one close vote gives the reason as this is opinion based. In what way is this opinion based? Either it is or it is not, based on the definition of a genetic algorithm.

Comment: How many generations are there? Is this limited to one generation?

Comment: No, the limit is in the population's "citizens". There is only one /generation

Comment: Why is there only one generation? It would be pretty pointless if there was only one generation wouldn't it?

Comment: It certainly looks like an attempt at a genetic algorithm, whether it works or not is a different question.

Comment: Technically, this *is* producing multiple child entities, but it seems to be discarding all of them except the one that is most fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are a lot of ambiguous definitions in the field of AI, my understanding is that:

1. An [***evolutionary algorithm (AE)***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_computation) is an algorithm that has a (set of) solution(s) and by mutating them somehow (crossover is here also seen as "mutating"), you eventually end up with better solution(s).
2. A [***genetic algorithm (GA)***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) supports the concept of a *crossover* where two or more "solutions" produce new solutions.

But the terms are sometimes mixed. Mind however that crossover is definitely not the only way to produce new individuals (there are more ways than genetic algorithms to produce better solutions), like:

- Simulated Annealing (SA);
- Tabu Search (TS);
- ...

But as said earlier there is always a lot of discussion what the terms really mean and most papers on probabilistic combinatorial optimization state clearly what they mean with the terms.

So according to the above definition, your program is an evolutionary algorithm, but not a genetic one: it always has a population of one after each iteration. Furthermore your program only accepts a new child if it is better than its parent making it a [***Local Search (LS)***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_(optimization)) algorithm. The problem with local search algorithms is that - if the mutation space of some/all solutions is a subset of the solution space - local search algorithms can get stuck forever in a local optimum. Even if that is not the case, they can get stuck in a local optimum for a very long time.

Here that is not a problem since there are *no* local optima (but this is of course an easy problem). More hard (and interesting) problems usually have (a lot) of local optima.

Local Search is not a bad technique if it collaborates with other techniques that help get the system out of the local optimum again. Other evolutionary techniques such as simulated annealing will accept a worse solution with small probability (depending how much worse the solution is, and how far we are in the evolutionary process).

Comment: It is my understanding that the point of a genetic algorithm is to generate a population only so that it can *select* the most appropriate one for the next generation. That is *exactly* what it is doing. Discarding each child until it is fit enough. It generates several child entities it just doesn't hang onto them.

Comment: Than you so mush for this documentation. Now I understand everything.

Comment: I'd note that while your points about getting stuck on a local optimum are correct in general, the fitness function used in the question has no possible local optimum other than the global optimum.

Comment: @Octopus: but that is also the case with for instance simulaed annealing that discards until a better solution or some probability. From that moment the child becomes the parent.

Comment: Your link to the wikipedia entry for [*genetic algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) basically says in the first sentence that GA belong to the larger class of EA, in other words all GA are EA. In the first section under methodology it says that a GA requires 2 things. I don't think either one is missing. It seems to me that the code in the OP is both a GA and and EA. What specifically, is in the *above definition* that contradicts that conclusion? Just trying to understand, you seem to know this better than I do.

Comment: It is a good question, why haven't you upvoted it? Obviously, you thought it was worth your while to provide an answer.

Comment: @Octopus: than what makes simulated annealing not a genetic algorithm?

Comment: This question is discuted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355630/should-providing-an-answer-automatically-count-as-an-upvote-to-a-question) on Meta.

Comment: @Willem, I have no idea what Simulated Annealing is or whether or not it is in fact a GA. I'll take your word for it that it is not. So is the main distinction that a GA combines two solutions to produce a new one while an EA only needs one prior?